# CocoaPods v0.39.0 errors with Facebook SDK v4.7

Tags: swift2, cocoapods, ios9, facebook-ios-sdk, xcode7-beta4

## Old Cocoapods Configuration

I am using Xcode 7 Beta 4. Initially I was using Cocoapods version 0.38.2 and when I ran `pod install --verbose` in Terminal it said it downloaded dependencies for Bolts, FBSDKCoreKit, FBSDKLoginKit, FBSDKShareKit, FBSDKMessengerShareKit, and Pods for **iOS 8.1**. With this setup my app compiled successfully. Below is the Podfile and Objective-C Bridging File that I used to import the Facebook SDK (so Swift recognises its referenced methods and Objective-C classes). Note that the specific versions shown in my Podfile are also the versions that get installed even if I do not explicitly specify them at the time of this writing.

#### Podfile

```
xcodeproj '/Users/<my_username>/MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'
pod "FBSDKCoreKit", "~> 4.7.0";
pod "FBSDKLoginKit", "~> 4.7.0";
pod "FBSDKShareKit", "~> 4.7.0";
pod "FBSDKMessengerShareKit", "~> 1.3.1";
```

#### MyAppObjCBridging.h

```
#ifndef MyAppObjCBridging_h
#define MyAppObjCBridging_h

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <FBSDKMessengerShareKit/FBSDKMessengerShareKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>

#endif
```

## Problems encountered when updating to Cocoapods v0.39.0 (from v0.38.2)

The console showed the message "CocoaPods 0.39.0 is available. To update use: gem install cocoapods. Until we reach version 1.0 the features of CocoaPods can and will change. We strongly recommend that you use the latest version at all times.", so I installed the this latest version of Cocoapods 0.39.0 by executing `sudo gem install cocoapods` in Terminal.

But when I compiled my app it gave me the following errors:

*/Users//MyApp/MyApp/MyAppObjCBridging.h:14:9: 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found*

In Xcode I "Product > Clean" (CMD+SHIFT+K), but this did not make any difference. So I ran `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` in Terminal (which listed 0.38.2 and 0.39.0 as the versions that were currently installed) and selected version 0.39.0 from the list to uninstall the latest version and revert back to 0.38.2. I then ran `pod install --verbose`. When I tried to compile my app it compiled successfully and ran in Simulator again.

## Question 1

Why does it give the error that it can't find "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h" when I use Cocoapods version 0.39.0 instead of the older version 0.38.2?

## Question 2

If when using Cocoapods version 0.38.2 (the version that compiles with my app) I decided to add `platform :ios, '9.0'` to the first line of my Podfile (above its existing contents) and run `pod install --verbose` in Terminal, the Terminal messages tell me that it installs each pod target for iOS 9.0 (instead of iOS 8.1) (i.e. `- Installing target`FBSDKCoreKit`iOS 9.0`). 
When I then run my app it successfully compiles and opens in Simulator and displays some new warnings associated with iOS9, most of which I understand. However I do not understand why this one appears. Why is this warning appearing?:

*ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Ls/code/swift/FreeWifiSearch/FreeWifiSearch/build/Debug-iphoneos'*

## Question 3

When using Cocoapods version 0.38.2 (the version that compiles with my app), if I decided to add `use_frameworks!` to the first line of my Podfile, and `platform :ios, '9.0'` to the second line of my Podfile (above its existing contents), and then run `pod install --verbose` in Terminal, the Terminal messages tell me that it installs each pod target for iOS 9.0 (instead of iOS 8.1).

When I then run my app the following errors appear:

- Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSDKLoginButton'
- Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSDKLoginManager'
- Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSDKLoginBehaviour'

Why does adding `use_frameworks!` to the top of my Podfile prevent me from using the Facebook SDK identifiers? (noting that when I don't have `use_frameworks!` at the top of my Podfile my app successfully compiles and runs in Xcode Simulator, and I can successfully retrieve a Facebook SDK Access Token and login to Facebook)

Answer (score 0):

Since posting the original questions the following was performed and resulted in no compiler errors:

- Updated from Xcode 7 Beta 4 to Xcode 7.1.1 by downloading latest from App Store
- Added `use_frameworks!` and `platform :ios, '9.0'` to top of Podfile
- Changed deployment target to iOS 9.0: Project Settings > Targets > General > Deployment Info > Deployment Target > 9.0
- Updated CocoaPods to v0.39 with `sudo gem install cocoapods`
- Reinstalled pods with `pod update --verbose`
- Added `import FBSDKLoginKit` above the class containing Facebook SDK methods
- Performed Clean (Shift+CMD+K) and Run (CMD+R) in Xcode to test on device

Answer (score 0):

Add `"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit"` in your target's Header Search Paths in Build Settings

For me it's OK now(CocoaPods 0.39, FBSDK 4.10)